# How to allow webapp to create files in DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a set of protected spreadsheet files that couple of users have an access to. Each of them has a script that uses functions from one library that trigger web app (that allows users to run functions as admin).

I want to give users an option of creating a copy of a given spreadsheet file. Now, if the user uses the "File" -> "create copy" then:

1. becomes an owner of the file (admin has to be an owner!) and user has to change it manually
2. protection is turned off on the user - admin has to change it manually.

I have decided to add the code to the webapp that is run on the admin account:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy();
```

This way copy of the file would be made from the admin account. It means that the admin would be an owner of the file and protection would work on the users.

Unfortunately, I get an error:

> Exception: Nie masz uprawnień, aby wywołać: DriveApp.getFileById. Wymagane uprawnienia: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

I understand that the web app does not have an access to the google drive.
Is it possible to allow only this web app to create new files in the drive?

Or is there any other way (without webapp) for user to create a copy of the file and automate: turning on protection on the user and changing owner of the file?

```
In webapp File -> Proterties -> Scopes I have found:
```

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Script in file:

```
function stworzKopiePliku(){
  Kosztoryslibrary.stworzKopiePliku();
}
```

Script in library:

```
var url = "...";
function stworzKopiePliku(url){
  stworzKopieP(url);
}

function stworzKopieP() {
  var urlScript = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); 
  var type = "stworzKopiePliku";
  var urlParam = (url+"?urlScript="+urlScript+"&type="+type+"&fileId="+fileId);  

  var html = "<script>window.open('" + urlParam + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, "skrypt w trakcie działania...");
}
```

Webapp:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var urlScript = e.parameter.urlScript;
  var type = e.parameter.type;
  var fileId = e.parameter.fileId;

  if(type == "stworzKopiePliku"){
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy();  
  }
```

}

I use the very similar code in many other functions and all works correctly. Only problem seems to be that the webapp does not have access to google drive to create files.

Comment: Click the "View" menu and choose "Show manifest file"  The file "appsscript.json" will open in the code editor.  If you don't see `"oauthScopes": [scope here]` then the scopes are handled internally.  You can explicitly set which scopes the Apps Script project will  use in the "appsscript.json"  (manifest) file.  When you run some code, the code checks for what scopes are authorized, and prompts you to authorize a new scope if needed.  Does your appsscript.json file have a setting for `"oauthScopes": [scope here]` ?

Comment: In the appsscript.json I have found only:
`{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}`

Comment: Your user need to authorize the web app. running any function directly should trigger authorization

Comment: Where will the `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy();` code be running from?  A project bound to the Sheet?  Or the Web App?  If it's run from the web app, then copying a file will put the file into the Drive of the owner of the Web App because the Web App is executing as `"USER_DEPLOYING"` which is the owner of the Web App.

Comment: I'd build the webapp as a standalone and put all of the support files in a shared drive and dont hardwire any fileId's or import access codes in the webapp.  Always fetch them from support files in the shared drive.  That way you can deploy as current user and anyone.  The people that you want to give access to need to have a gmail account and they need to have access to that shared account.  Without access to the shared account all that anyone can see is the first page with no data and no way to get it.  Can't make shared drives? Well, it may be time to step up to  a paid account.

Comment: @TheMaster Only authorization appears when script is run directly from file. Than code redirects to the library. Code in library opens url. That triggers the webapp that is run by admin. So it seems to not be possible to authorize webapp as user. 

Running webapp as user is not posiible. Admin must run it. It's the point why I use it. In the script there are many actions on protected cells that only admin has an access to.

Comment: @AlanWells makeCopy() is run from WebApp. Only this way I can make Admin always an owner of the new file and do not sustain keep protection on users. Admin is the owner of the: spreadsheet, library script, webapp, google drive. No matter who triggers the function (admin or user) webapp is not able to create files in the Drive.

Comment: @Cooper I have paid version with shared drive. I am not sure if I understand what you mean correctly. But running webapp by anyone else than admin ruins my strategy. Files contain protected cells. Only script that is run from webapp by admin can execute code. Webapp used by user would be blocked because of the protection.

Comment: Show your full script

Comment: @TheMaster Added as an edit.

Comment: In https://myaccount.google.com/permissions does the web app have drive permission?

Comment: Try running `doGet()` manually from the script editor using admin account(the account that deployed the web app).